# Why use CallAdapter.factory in Retrofit?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, android-livedata

1.Why use CallAdapter.factory in Retrofit?
2.You can explain the function of the following method
Thank you very much for your time

```
class LiveDataCallAdapterFactoryForRetrofit : CallAdapter.Factory() {
    override fun get(
        returnType: Type,
        annotations: Array<Annotation>,
        retrofit: Retrofit
    ): CallAdapter<*, *>? {
        if (getRawType(returnType) != LiveData::class.java) {
            return null
        }
        val observableType = getParameterUpperBound(0, returnType as ParameterizedType)
        val rawObservableType = getRawType(observableType)
        require(rawObservableType == Resource::class.java) { "type must be a resource" }
        require(observableType is ParameterizedType) { "resource must be parameterized" }
        val bodyType = getParameterUpperBound(0, observableType)
        return LiveDataCallAdapter<Any>(bodyType)
    }
```

Comment: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-introduction-to-call-adapters